# SAS running a macro loop for n and p generating variables--> then creating a macro loop which has n and p as arguments

Tags: math, statistics, sas, sas-macro

As the title states im trying to illustrate the law of large numbers through bernoulli(p) by running a macro loop to generate output in the log. However with the following code i am getting no output what so ever. Following code is below.

Code:

```html
%macro LLN(n=10, p=0.6);
  %let sum = 0; %let mean = 0;
   data LLN; 
%do i = 1 %to &n;
x = rand("Bernoulli", &p); 
sum = sum + x;
mean = sum / i;
output; 
%end;
run;
%mend LLN;
```

Comment: The code you show is mixing macro and base in ways that don't interact in the way you seem to expect (i.e. data step variable assignment does not implicitly impact variables in macro scope).  Focus more on getting experience with SAS coding sans macro.  It will better position you for macro coding.

Comment: Get the SAS code to work first before trying to use macro variables or macro logic to generate the SAS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the SAS code to work properly for some value of N and P first.

So this code will create 10 observations.

```
data LLN; 
  do i = 1 to 10;
    x = rand("Bernoulli", 0.6); 
    sum + x;
    mean = sum / i;
    output; 
  end;
run;
```

If you just want the final observation and not all of the partial sums then either move the OUTPUT statement outside the loop, or delete it since SAS will write the observation at the end of the step when there is no explicit output statement.

```
data LLN; 
  do i = 1 to 10;
    x = rand("Bernoulli", 0.6); 
    sum + x;
  end;
  mean = sum / 10;
run;
```

Now you can try to convert it to a macro by replacing 10 with &N and 0.6 with &P.

```
%let n=10;
%let p=0.6;
data LLN; 
  do i = 1 to &n;
    x = rand("Bernoulli", &p); 
    sum + x;
  end;
  mean = sum / &n;
run;
```

Once you see that works you are ready to create a macro with parameters N and P.

```
%macro LLN(n, p);
data LLN; 
  do i = 1 to &n;
    x = rand("Bernoulli", &p); 
    sum + x;
  end;
  mean = sum / &n;
run;
%mend LLN;
%LLN(n=10,p=0.6)
```

Comment: This is perfect, however how do i output it to the log with a %put statement?

Comment: You write to the log with a PUT statement in normal SAS code.  Add the statement `put p= i= mean= ;` What would you want the macro to write to the log? The only thing the macro knows about is the value of the parameters you passed in and you can see that already in the SAS log from the call to the macro.

Answer (score 2):

There are three points to improve:

1. You don't really need a macro. The do loop can be done in normal data step.
2. If you want to use macro variable `i` in your data step to join the calculation with data step variables, you should use `&i`.
3. The initial way of `sum` and `mean` is for macro variable, but you truly use them as data step variables.

I suggest you to use a data step:

```
data test;
  do i=1 to 10000;
    x = rand("Bernoulli", 0.6); 
    sum + x;
    mean = sum / i;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

A macro-ization of @whymath code would take argument for the loop `max` and `p` parameter of the `rand()` function.

Example:

A use of this macro creates a single data set.  Why mean is calculated at each loop iteration?  Do you want the intermediate mean in you study of LLN?  If so, add an `OUTPUT` inside the loop.  If not, after the loop concludes compute `mean = sum / &N`.  You probably also want the macro to accept a random number seed for reproducibility in future runs.

```
%macro LLN (N=1000, p=0.6, out=, seed=.);  /* . is a random seed */
  data &out (label="LLN: N=&N, p=&p");
    call streaminit(&seed);
    do i=1 to &N;
      x = rand("Bernoulli", &p); 
      sum + x;
      mean = sum / i;
    end;
    * mean = sum / &N; * maybe? ;
  run;

%mend;
```

However, you can also compute the sum & mean for various combinations of N & p in a single data step and do some sort of visualizaton involving `by` and `group` concepts.

```
data LLN_study;
  do p = 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9;
    do N = 1e3, 1e4, 1e5;

      call missing (sum, mean);
      do i = 1 to N;
        x = rand("Bernoulli", p); 
        sum + x;
        mean = sum / i;
        * OUTPUT ;  /* uncomment if you want every sum & mean for each N,p,i */
      end;
      * mean = sum / N;
      * OUTPUT ;  /* uncomment if you want every sum & mean for each N,p */
    end; /* p variation */
  end; /* N variation */
run;

proc sgplot data=LLN_study;
  series y=mean x=i / group=N;
  where mod(i,10)=1;
  by p;
run;
```

Comment: Is there missing some step, the dataset is not sorted on `p`. By the way, I wrote an email to you last week, did you see it? ^_^